# CURL vs fsockopen chunking

Tags: php, curl, chunked-encoding, fsockopen

This may seem kind of weird.. but I need to evaluate/parse chunks being sent over HTTP with PHP.

It's of note to say that the HTTP stream may never end. Is there any way I can parse chunks **as I get them** with CURL?

Or do I have to resort to some home-brewed `fsockopen()` solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the option `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. You can define a callback that will be called when there's new data in the response. See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).